# Investigate the uniform convergence of a series of functions $\sum^{+\infty}_{n=1} \frac{x}{n^2}$ for $x \in \mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis

> Investigate the uniform convergence of a series of functions $\sum^{+\infty}_{n=1} \frac{x}{n^2}$ for $x \in \mathbb R$

**My try:**
$$|f_{n}(x)|=|\frac{x}{n^2}|=\frac{|x|}{n^2}\le\frac{|x|}{n^2}$$So from Weierstrass M-test series $\sum^{+\infty}_{n=1} \frac{x}{n^2}$ is uniform convergence because number series $\sum^{+\infty}_{n=1} \frac{|x|}{n^2}$ is convergent.
However I saw other sollution and author of this is thinking that my answer is not true.
 
Can you rate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the series is uniformly convergent then $\frac x {n^{2}}$ tends to $0$ uniformly. This implies that there is an integer $m$ such that $n \geq m$ implies $|\frac x {n^{2}}|<1$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$. To get a contradiction from this take $n=m$ and $x=m^{2}$.